# How to stop redirection in bash

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I use :

```
exec >script.log 2>&1
```

in my script to redirect all output to a file. At the end of the script I would like to print a message to the screen. How do I stop the redirection?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can call `exec` again to restore the original descriptors. You'll need to have saved them somewhere.

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2 1>script.log 2>&1
… logged portion …
exec 1>&3 2>&4
echo >&2 "Done"
```

Inside the logged portion, you can use the original descriptors for one command by redirecting to the extra descriptors.

```
echo "30 seconds remaining" >&3
```

Alternatively, you can put the logged portion of your script inside a compound command and redirect that compound command. This doesn't work if you want to use the original descriptors in a trap somewhere within that redirected part.

```
{
… logged portion …
} >script.log 2>&1
echo >&2 "Done"
```

Comment: The remark about echoing to `>&3` makes this my preferred solution. Thanks (again)!

Answer (score 6):

Use additinal fd 3 and 4 for stdout and stderr and simply redirect 1 and 2 to them at the end of your script:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
exec >script.log 2>&1

echo "Some code"

exec >&3 2>&4
echo "Done"
```

Comment: This returns an error :
`exec 3>/dev/stdout 4>/dev/stderr
-bash: /dev/stdout: Permission denied`

Comment: This error may occur when you're trying to launch your script within another user. Do you use your script via sudo?

Comment: Yes, that's it: I did a su to another account and ran the code. The script I'm writing will be run via sudo, so I'll run into the same problem there. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I believe there is some elegant solution, unfortunately I know the only option, that may be absolutely unacceptable from security point of view: add your target user to your initial user primary group and add group write permissions for /proc/self/fd/1 before script launch. ( or even more vulnerable - just make temporary write permission for all and remove it right after the script is finished without group changes ).

Comment: @Willem This is easily fixed by using file descriptors instead of reopening the files, see my edit.

Comment: @Gilles: works perfect, thanks! (need to remind myself to read up on file descriptors :-)

Answer (score 1):

First you should check whether or not you have a tty at all.

```
if tty -s; then
    echo "Hello, World" > $(tty)
fi
```

Comment: Note, that this way can't feed output to external program.

Comment: It's not necessary to use the external `tty` utility. You can redirect to the special device `/dev/tty`.