# How do I turn off redirection once I've turned it on?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I found a great solution at [Redirect all subsequent commands' stderr using exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61931/redirect-all-subsequent-commands-stderr-using-exec/61936#61936?newreg=0675eec068c04fdb8aaea6be40dbae05).

I used the example:

```
exec > >(tee $somelog) 2>&1
```

...and managed to get everything to `tee` great. Now, how to I turn it off again?

Comment: Appears to have been answered here:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80988/how-to-stop-redirection-in-bash

Comment: Thank you for the link.  My problem is that I just used the example, and it worked.  Can't say I understand it.  Hence, I do not know what was set to what before I redirected it. So I don't know what to change back. Or to what to set it.  Basically, if I ran: "exec > >(tee $rrmasterlog) 2>&1" to set it, what do I run to turn it off?

Comment: Please [read this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91716/79743).

Answer (score 4):

The best solution if you plan it in advance is probably to save the descriptors first, or to do your redirections in a subsidiary scope, as in [the question linked in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80988/how-to-stop-redirection-in-bash).

If you didn't do that, though, then you can restore writing directly to the terminal with:

```
exec > $(tty)
```

[provided that](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tty.html) you haven't redirected standard input as well.

If you *have* redirected standard input, you can use:

```
exec > /dev/tty
```

, which is also fractionally faster.

---

Those reset standard output to the terminal. To reset standard error specifically, use:

```
exec 2> ...
```

for whichever option you chose from above.

---

If you're just stuck and want to get out of it, note that simply exiting and restarting the shell will get you back to normal as well.